Easily navigating through text file, using table of contents?
I have a long-winded text file with thousands of lines which makes it very difficult to jump from lines to lines to find what I need. This document is categorized into dozens of different subjects.
So it looks something like this:

List of newspapers in Japan: Asahi, Mainichi, Yomiuri, Sankei… etc…
List of horror movie released from 1994 to 2015: Scream, Saw, Grudge… etc…
List of influencer from India: Aishwarya Rai, Madhuri Dixit, Virat Kohli… etc…

This is just for exemplary purpose and the actual list is much much much longer with many many more categories.
I can search for keywords using Find dialog but it's not very convenient in that you should always type in something and there's chance for more than one match results found. Not the best option.
So here does clickable Table of Contents come to my mind. just like PDF document's sidebar that show the list of titles and by clicking one it would directly jump to the line where the title lies in the actual document.
I am not very experienced in coding but willing to learn if I have to.
But the simpler it is, the better, of course. I am not creating the elegant looking website full of animation and special effects here anyway, but just want to seek out the easiest and fastest way to lead me to the plain-texted contents I want to read anytime I want. And the document is frequently updated so I wish I could read and edit the document in one place.
Oh, btw my main go-to text editor is AkelPad for anyone wondering, not that I mean I must stick to that specific editor. Anything will be great as far as it does the job. if a program is lightweight, much better!

Please, don't cross post

Instead of trying to code a solution for your unusual format, it'd be much more efficient and faster to convert your text to a known format that supports these kind of features much more easily.
For example, Markdown. If you use headers properly, generating a table of contents with different kinds of software should be easy. Here is an example of Visual Studio Code Markdown All in One plugin which can generate table of contents - all you have to do is run Create Table of Contents command. Similarly, Markdown Monster software supports such a feature with e.g. View -> Document Outline sidebar that doesn't modify the file.


As to how to convert it quickly, it depends on the actual contents. If you always use numeric categories in each line as in provided example in the question, you could use:
^\d+\.(.*?) : (.*?)$

with replacement:
# $1\n$2

to add the main headers (#) for the list names and place the lists in a separate line.

Thank you a lot. Is it safe to say markdown is simplified and easy to learn html alternative? Is it possible to hide codeview panel when I just need to read the doc?

No, it's not an HTML alternative. They have entirely different puposes. HTML would never be used for notes. It's used for defining website and application layouts. Markdown also sometimes with certain tools, but it's mostly a language for quick text formatting, due to easy to remember and fast to insert syntax.

As for hiding code view, there are definitely full screen previews available, you can also drag stuff around so that the preview and outline take up most of the space.

AkelPad does include a bookmarks Plugin (see description below).
In answer to, Is there better with such similar features?
One of the better "Text Editors" with many program related features and a bookmarks plug-in is Notepad++ However it is primarily Windows only. (But WINE variants may be possible see @Chester-Gillon comment below), but portable is very suitable for any Windows VMs.

I do not suggest using it for the task of adding bookmarks into a binary PDF, you can do that as it is capable of doing so, but you need to know how to hand edit PDFs (and perhaps "double up" with other Hex/PDF Viewer/Editing).

NOTE that AkelPad does include a bookmarks Plugin. So does have some basic abilities as a Windows NotePad enhancer. Thus unclear why that is not sufficient ? However to boost that functionality more could involve custom coding by the author or similar! and I note little activity in recent years.  https://akelpad.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=158


Notepad++ (WINE) is available as snap for Ubuntu - see Install Notepad++ (WINE) on Ubuntu. I have used that to run Notepad++ on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

Thank you for the heads up. Yes, that'll do the trick but that's temporary. bookmarked lines are remembered only until I clear the recent history, which I unfortunately do from time to time. That is why I'd like permanent solution, as it would be very frustrating to bookmark every one of them every time the history is cleared. I wonder if the way NPP's bookmark works is similar to AkelPad.
